# In Delphi, what is a parameter directive?

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal

I am learning about different types of directives in Delphi. The documentation lists three types of directives: switch, parameter, and conditional.

However, the documentation gives a one-line vague description about parameter directives without giving any examples:

> Parameter directives specify parameters that affect the compilation, such as file names and memory sizes.
> [Delphi Directives](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Delphi_compiler_directives#Parameter_Directives)

Can someone explain what are parameters in a directive and examples of a parameter directive.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linked page shows examples of parameters directives in common list:

```
{$I TYPES.INC}
{$M 32768,40960}
```

They are: including code piece from file `TYPES.INC` and setting `minstacksize,maxstacksize` memory sizes

You can see parameter directive (`Resource file`) in every VCL application:

```
implementation
{$R *.dfm}
```

You are right that help doesn't separate directives explicitly by these types (perhaps I've missed something)

In my mind, switch directives mostly contain switch `+/-` or `ON/OFF` like `$DEBUGINFO ON`, while parameter ones require string/int parameters.

But  `$A: (Align fields)` directive may contain both switch and alignment value, so I believe it is parameter directive, because +/- are just synonyms for `A1` and `A8`